# Induction hypothesis confusion

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

Let below be $f(n)$
 \begin{cases} 
      n & 0 \leq n < 2 \\
      3f(n-2) + 2f(n-3) & n > 2 
   \end{cases}

Prove $f(n) < 2^n, \forall n \geq 0$

Base case:

Let $n = 0$, then

$f(0) = 0 < 1 = 2^0$ as wanted

let $n = 1$

$f(1) = 1 < 2 = 2^1$ as wanted

let $n = 2$

$f(2) = 2 < 4 = 2^2$ as wanted

all by definition of $f(n)$ and $2^n$

Inductive step: let $n > 2$

Suppose $f(j) < 2^n$ whenever $0 \leq j < n$ [I.H]

$f(n) = 3f(n-2) + 2f(n-3)$ [def of n > 2]

$< 3 * 2^{n-2} + 2 * 2^{n-3}$ [IH]

$= 2^{n-3} (6 + 2)$

$= 2^n$

---

My question is: The induction step / IH states this: Suppose $f(j) < 2^n$ whenever $0 \leq j < n$ [I.H]

What does this mean?

And would it be wrong if I let it be $0 \leq j \leq n$ instead of less than n, if so why?

Comment: If you let $0\leq j \leq n$, then you must show the truth of relation for $f(n+1)$ instead of $f(n)$.

Comment: Note that the IH should be to suppose that $f(j)<2^j$ whenever $0\le j<n$ (but of course if you can get by with $f(j)<2^n$ that's OK, since that would imply that $f(j)<2^j$).

Comment: He needs $f(j)<2^j$ for all $j<n$, which is fine.